# How can I position these thumbnails under the slider?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

So, I found this cool css/html slider on a website, so I downloaded the code, and am going to study it. I've started to edit it and style it to my own needs, and I came upon this problem: when I added an image of a bigger size than the originals, the navigation thumbnails got covered. I want them **under** the slider.

CSS and HTML

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
.slider {
  width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 320px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.slider>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch'] {
  display: none;
}
.slider label {
  margin: 18px 0 0 18px;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.slider label img {
  display: block;
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
  border-color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch'] ~ img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked" />
  <label for="id2">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X800" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3" />
  <label for="id3">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100/FF0000" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/640X320/FF0000" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4" />
  <label for="id4">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100/FF9900" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/640X320/FF9900" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5" />
  <label for="id5">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100/FFFF99" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/640X320/FFFF99" />
</div>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thought I don't understand your problem, but I don't see it being replicated in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by restricting the width and height of the img to its container:

```
.slider > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Now, let's centre the image, this will look a lot better for images that don't span the width of the container:

`.slider > img` gets `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` (placed next to the existing scale transform).

### Working Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
.slider {
  width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 320px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.slider>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch'] {
  display: none;
}
.slider label {
  margin: 18px 0 0 18px;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.slider label img {
  display: block;
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
  border-color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch'] ~ img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-50%);
}
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked" />
  <label for="id2">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/640X320" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3" />
  <label for="id3">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100/FF0000" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000X1000/FF0000" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4" />
  <label for="id4">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100/FF9900" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/640X320/FF9900" />

  <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5" />
  <label for="id5">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100/FFFF99" width="100" />
  </label>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/640X320/FFFF99" />
</div>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a **max-width** and a **max-height** to your images so that they always fit in the container without stretching.

```
.slider>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;

  /* ADD THESE LINES */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```